# make g77 command not found

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-warnings, g77

I am trying to make a project:

https://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/FTP/Code/

it reports:

```
make: g77 command not found.
```

I saw this line in Makefile:

```
FF = g77
```

Can I change 'g77' here to something else to compile in the current OS, ex: Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Did you make any attempt to research the issue? Such as searching for exactly "g77 command not found"? Have you tried any of the results?

Comment: The compiler is generally `gfortran` or `gfortran-7`. Check with `type -p gfortran` or `type -p gfortran-7`. (just edit the `Makefile` and change `g77` to `gfortran`)

Comment: Works fine, e.g. `Copy:           11928.6     0.013600     0.013413     0.013749`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
FF = g77
```

to

```
FF = gfortran
```

works.